# Спарсить карточки товаров на озоне на Python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, web-scraping

Получается взять первые 4 товара, остальные подгружаются с помощью скрипта как я понимаю, но вот как их достать не понимаю

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.ozon.ru/category/podguzniki-i-trusiki-30749/?type=37543"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

items = soup.find_all("div", class_="rj2")

for item in items:
    title = item.find("span", class_="p6j").next
    print(title.text)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Динамический сайт. Ловите запросы между сайтом и браузером. Если не знаете как рыбачить используйте селенимум.